# Grails 3 Fields Plugin - display property values in place of hasMany Object:id using f:display tag

Tags: grails

I have an domain called Project with a hasMany relationship like

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [prefixes: Prefix] 
}
```

In the Project show.gsp using `<f:display bean="project" />` the list of Prefix displays the id's like com.example.Prefix:1

I want to replace this with something more meaningful by concatenating two properties of Prefix like 'number' and 'name' with a hyphen in between. In Grails 2 without Fields plugin I would have done something like this:

```
<ol>
...
  <li class="fieldcontain">
  <span id="prefixes-label" class="property-label">
  <g:message code="prefixes.label" default="Prefixes" /></span>

  <g:each in="${project.prefixes}" var="p">
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="prefixes-label">
    <g:link controller="prefix" action="show" id="${p.id}">${p.number} - ${p.name}</g:link></span>
   </g:each>
  </li>
...
</ol>
```

I've tried creating a grails-app/views/project/show/_displayWrapper.gsp with the above code except replacing 'project' with 'bean' and the `<f:display bean="project">` in show.gsp but I still got the default page.

How do I use the `<f:display bean="project">` style tag to achieve this?

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by creating a default views/project/show/_displayWrapper.gsp for my regular properties:

```
<li class="fieldcontain">
    <span id="${label}" class="${label}"><g:message code="${label}" default="${label}" /></span>
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${label}"><g:fieldValue bean="${project}" field="${property}"/></span>
</li>
```

And a specific one for my hasMany prefixes in views/project/show/prefixes/_displayWrapper.gsp

```
<li class="fieldcontain">
    <span id="${label}" class="${label}"><g:message code="${label}" default="${label}" /></span>
    <g:each in="${value}" var="p">
        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${label}"><g:link controller="prefix" action="show" id="${p.id}">${p.number} - ${p.name}</g:link></span>
    </g:each>
</li>
```

And then in my show.gsp I replaced

```
<f:display bean="project" />
```

With

```
<ol class="property-list">
    <f:display bean="project" property="number"/>
    <f:display bean="project" property="name"/>
    ...
    <f:display bean="project" property="prefixes"/>
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you put inside these ${label} values ??